# Ajax data возвращает весь html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form, sendmail

Сделал Ajax запрос после отправки и проверки на валидность инпутов.

```
            var data = {
                name: name_val,
                email: mail_val,
                message: comment_val
            }
            console.log(data) 
           // тут выводятся правильные значения
           // {name: "123", email: "mail@mail.ru", message: "123"}

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
               url: "index.php",  
               data: data,
               success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
               // тут выводится весь код html страницы
            }
```

Из-за чего такой эффект? До этого использовал в качества data

```
var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //или
var form_data = form.serialize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B

```
success: function(data){
```

`data` - это то, что возвращает Ваш код в `url: "index.php",`.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы проверка формы происходила в этом же index.php?

Comment: @РомаХр Я не понимаю вопрос. `index.php` - это Ваш код на сервере. Там может быть любая логика для проверки данных, пришедших в запросе.